# Multi-language site in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

For SEO purposes I'd like to include the locale of my Laravel project pages  in the url, such as http://localhost/en or http://localhost/nl/about.

In trying to achieve this I have found a few tutorials and packages, but I'm not entirely happy with them. The most popular suggestion is mcamara's laravel-localization package, but creating URLs requires a very long function call. Other packages are either for older Laravel versions or offer a lot of functionality I don't need, which would only clutter my code and database.

[Marwelln's tutorial](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/example-on-how-to-use-multiple-locales-in-your-laravel-5-website) seems perfect: it modifies URLs the way I want, works with the default URL helpers like action(), url() and route() and doesn't create unnecessary database tables. However, this tutorial seem to be for Laravel 5.0 and not compatible with Laravel 5.4. Could anyone help me to achieve such URL modification in the newest Laravel version in the most basic way?

Comment: I'm looking for same if you have the project please share.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

In your RouteServiceProvider.php add these lines at the beginnig of the map() method:

```
    $locale = $request->segment(1);
    if($locale) {
        $this->app->setLocale($locale);
        $this->prefix = $locale;
    }
```

And the mapWebRoutes() method should look like this:

```
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    $parameters = [
        'middleware' => 'web',
        'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    ];
    if ($this->prefix) {
        $parameters['prefix'] = $this->prefix;
    }

    Route::group($parameters, function ($router) {
        require base_path('routes/web.php');
    });
}
```

Then follow the rest of the instructions in the link of the example you provide. I guess that should be all.

NOTE: the line $this->app->setLocale($locale) has not much sense since you are doing that on the middleware.